# Closed recordset returned (instead of error) when executing command after connection loss

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ado, recordset

I'm trying to make an ADO (not ADO.NET) application resilient against connectivity failures:

- Shutdown the SQL server service in the "Services" panel
- Application should react gracefully and allow a reconnect

The first problem was to detect the connection loss. When taking SQL server offline, the `State` property of an open connection object still contains `adStateOpen`, and this does not change if a query fails due to a lost connection. [It appears](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that checking `SQLState = "08S01"` can be used to detect a lost connection -- if executing a query raises an error.

However, I've noticed that some (not all) queries issued by `Command.Execute` return a closed `Recordset` (!) instead of raising an error; the same happens when I create `Recordset` object up front and then call `Recordset.Open`. [The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are not particularly helpful here -- they indicate that the recordset will be closed if the query does not return a value, but I wouldn't expect a *communication link failure* as a valid reason for not returning a value here...

It seems that this behavior is triggered by the presence of two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s with the same table on `uniqueidentifier` columns: A query without such joins, or with only one such join, throws an error (as expected) when the SQL server is down, whereas a query with two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s just returns a closed recordset.

Could someone shed light on this odd behavior? It's a tad difficult, but I can provide a minimal VB6 example on request. **EDIT**: A first attempt to construct a truly minimal example failed.

Specs: Up to date Windows 7 32-bit, SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: This is why people install services from the Linux world on Windows machines. This wouldn't have happened with MySQL or other such product. I'm not really into databases, but from my webserver experience, M$ servers are the worst. When you switch to things like PHP, you instantly recognize the nice features you only dreamt about in IIS/ASP.

Comment: @Zdenek: Now that's a nice attempt to start a flame war...

Comment: Not at all, although I can see how it may be seen as such. It is an opinion I have gained with first-hand experience. Yours may be different.

Comment: @Zdenek: Thanks. In this particular case it's not my choice to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to a weakly documented feature of ADO: If recordsets with `CursorType` set to `adUseServer` (the default!) are still opened when issuing a new query, a second connection will be established by ADO.